# How to raise Play's max_fetch_depth?

Tags: orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am getting NullPointerException when accessing member fields only 3 levels deep in my view template:

```
@tfz.modelTfzTyp.simulierteTfzTyp.typ
```

If I use getter functions instead, it works. But it is cumbersome.

I am using Ebean and I read that Hibernate has a `max_fetch_depth`. I am suspecting that something similar is causing my problems. How do I make Play load more objects eagerly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `max_fetch_depth` property.

Dynamic fetching is allowed by byte code enhancement on the models, and it works only for the getters.

See the official [documentation](http://play2-docs-snapshot.herokuapp.com/render/master/JavaEbean):

> Enhancement of direct Ebean field access (enabling lazy loading) is only applied to Java classes, not to Scala. Thus, direct field access from Scala source files (including standard Play 2 templates) does not invoke lazy loading, often resulting in empty (unpopulated) entity fields. To ensure the fields get populated, either (a) manually create getter/setters and call them instead, or (b) ensure the entity is fully populated before accessing the fields.